# Regarding benzoic acid and its effects

Tags: human-biology, gene-expression, food

One of the users on the chemistry s.e. mentioned that when benzoic acid forms in the body in response to other chemicals it might have a mutating effect on one's DNA. Is this true?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to that statement? Just so I can see it in a broader meaning and not just what another user mentioned. Thanks!

Comment: I  wrote in the question 'Regarding common preservatives and their effects' as user 128932 ; I commented after the question about benzoic acid..

Comment: Is that a link?

Comment: Can benzoic acid form in the body?

Comment: Is this a health risk?